# Alternative to Template Pattern where the implementation can have an attribute

Tags: c#, inheritance, events, attributes

I'm using a series of Template Pattern classes that represent different types of events.

```
internal abstract class DayEndingEvent : Event
{  
    internal void OnDayEnding(object? sender, DayEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsHooked) OnDayEndingImpl(sender, e);
    }

    protected abstract void OnDayEndingImpl(object? sender, DayEndingEventArgs e);
}
```

This pattern ensures that the implementation only runs if the event is "hooked", which allows other parts of the application to activate/deactivate the event by calling `Hook` and `Unhook` methods from the base `Event` class.

```
internal abstract class Event
{
    public bool IsHooked {get; private set;}

    public bool Hook() => !IsHooked && (IsHooked = true);

    public bool Unhook() => IsHooked && !(IsHooked = false);
}
```

(`Event` is obviously more complex than this, but this is enough to get the picture).
My `EventManager` can instantiate one of every implementation of this pattern and hook their `OnDayEnding` to the appropriate handler in an external API.

This has worked fine for a while, but now I have a new requirement to add prioritization to these classes. The only way to do so (and this is a limitation of the external API) is by adding attribute `[EventPriority]` to the event callback. But obviously I can't annotate `OnDayEnding` with a priority since that would set the priority of *all* implementations, which defeats the whole purpose.

The attribute will have no effect anywhere else but on the callback. The only other solution I can see is to remove the `Impl` and just make the callback itself abstract. But that means I'd have to manually check the `IsHooked` flag on every implementation, which is what I want to avoid.

So question is, can anybody sugest an alternative to this pattern that would both 1) allow me to have different implementations of the callback, to which I can add priority attributes, and 2) enforce the check for `IsHooked`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities I have come across recently when I encountered a similar problem:

Option one, have an entry method that has the required attributes:

```
public class SpecificImplementationClass1 : BaseClass, IInitializer 
{
    [SomeAttribute]
    public void CallMeToInitiate(SomeType input)
    {
        ExecuteCommonCode(input);
    }

    protected override void ExecuteSpecificCode(object input)
    {
        var typedInput = (SomeType) input;
        // ...execute whatever implementation-specific code here
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    protected void ExecuteCommonCode(object input)
    {
         // DoSomethingBefore(input);
         ExecuteSpecificCode(input);
         // DoSomethingAfter(input);
    }

    protected abstract void ExecuteSpecificCode(object input);
}

public interface IInitializer
{
    void CallMeToInitialize(SomeType input);
}

// Get all IInitializers through dependency injection and call "CallMeToInitialize(new SomeType())" on each
```

Option two, use the [template delegate pattern](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/08/30/template-delegate-pattern/)